# rsync exclude option with file names with spaces

Tags: backup, rsync

I have been trying to run rsync as follows;

```
rsync -av --exclude '/home/joe/VirtualBox*' /dst
```

where VirtualBox* denotes all files and directories under the directory 'VirtualBox VMs'

However, it does not appear how I specify this `--exclude` option, rsync tries to backup everything under the 'VirtualBox VMs' directory.

Tried using `--exclude=` , `--exclude={ }` but the result is the same.

Any ideas what I am doing wrong here?

Comment: The `exclude` option of rsync uses a relative path rather than an absolute one. Is this your full rsync line? The 'exclude' options will be relative to your source directory, which seems to be missing from your given command...

Comment: Thanks for the hint - it works with relative path specification for excluded files. Apologies for omitting the source directory which is /home/joe.

Comment: Careful: the syntax in the man page is --exclude=PATTERN (with =).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `exclude` option of rsync works on *relative* paths not *absolute* ones. So for your example something like the following will work:

```
rsync -avz --exclude 'directory' source_directory/ destination_directory/
```

In this generic example you can see that `--exclude 'directory'` assumes that `directory` is a *sub-directory* of `source_directory`.

I have included the `-z` option for the rsync line, compression gives a few small speed increases...

**Notes:**

- [How to Exclude Files and Directories with Rsync](https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-exclude-files-and-directories-with-rsync/): The page that got me to finally understand the `--exclude` option of rsync :)

Comment: Thanks - you saved a lot of pain and time.

Answer (score 1):

I needed an exclude with any of several arguments. After many trials and errors I found:

```
EXCLUDE='--exclude=/home/myname/VirtualBox*VMs/'
```

... which then worked correctly to exclude the "VirtualBox VMs" in
`rsync -autH .... $EXCLUDE ...`

Not yet clear about the rules ...